# Time between web3.eth.sendRawTransaction and transaction validated time on Bscscan

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py, bscscan

I'm making web3py contract transaction, using this code:

```
txn = contract.functions.bid(
    tokenId, 
    price
).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': 56,
    'gas': gasLimit,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce
})

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, private_key=privateKey)
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(web3.toHex(signed_txn.rawTransaction))
```

Then, I check transaction status on Bscscan
[image]

The transaction appeared on Bscscan at 05:54:42, but sendRawTransaction was at 05:54:39 (3 secs difference). Is it possible to minimize this time difference?

Answer (score 0):

### HOW TO HANDLE TRANSACTION SPEED?

For greater speed adjust the gas price (transaction fee) for your transaction. However, be aware that **Higher GWEI = Higher Speed = Higher Rates.**

[image]

If you don't define the gasPrice transaction object it will default to *web3.eth.getGasPrice()* which is often 5 gwei. **[[READ MORE]](http://https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#id4)**

**USE 5 GWEI FOR STANDARD TRANSACTION SPEED**

```
.buildTransaction({
'chainId': 56,
'gas': gasLimit,
'nonce': nonce
})
```

**USE 6 GWEI FOR FAST TRANSACTION SPEED**

```
.buildTransaction({
'chainId': 56,
'gasPrice': web3.toWei('6', 'gwei'),
'gas': gasLimit,
'nonce': nonce
})
```

**USE 7 GWEI FOR VERY FAST TRANSACTION SPEED**

```
.buildTransaction({
'chainId': 56,
'gasPrice': web3.toWei('7', 'gwei'),
'gas': gasLimit,
'nonce': nonce
})
```

**USE 15 GWEI OR MORE FOR INSTANT TRANSACTION SPEED**

```
.buildTransaction({
'chainId': 56,
'gasPrice': web3.toWei('7', 'gwei'),
'gas': gasLimit,
'nonce': nonce
})
```

Typically 7 GWEI is more than enough for most cases, being perhaps the best cost-benefit between speed and cost in gas fees.

However if you really need to guarantee instant transactions I recommend gasPrice of 15 GWEI or above.